# PhpStorm 2019 or newer - how to use Windows theme?

Tags: phpstorm

In PhpStorm 2016 I had this theme:

[image]

In PhpStorm 2019 the theme is missing:

[image]

How to use it?

Comment: Update to a newer version: current PhpStorm 2012.2 (and quite a few previous versions) have **Windows 10 Light** theme: https://i.imgur.com/Kssv5z9.png (at very least here on Windows 10 -- not sure what you will see there on your OS (looks like XP / classic theme)).

Comment: Or search for another Theme -- they can be installed just as any other plugin -- just search for `theme` keyword.

Comment: @LazyOne it is indeed a Windows 7 with a Classic theme. I tried 2021.2 and it looks different, there's gray everywhere. Can't I somehow export the 2016 theme and import it into newer ones?

Comment: You are welcome to try (somehow locate and extract in 2016 version; possibly pakage it as a plugin and install plugin "from ZIP") .. but 1) there were quite a lot of changes since then; 2) current GUI themes is different than L&F (Java Swing Look & Feel) that was present back then). I do not think it will work. You best way: 1) Find a modern suitable theme from current available; 2) Perhaps there is a plugin that allows customizing main theme colors at runtime (I do not know, maybe Material UI Theme -- just a random guess).